# NodeMCU não recebe os dados conforme eu envio via Protocolo UDP

Tags: python, c, arduino, redes, udp

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação simples, o objetivo é simplesmente enviar a leitura de um sensor conectado a um Arduino NodeMCU para um Raspberry PI, e realizar uma leitura parecida utilizando o Raspberry e enviar para o NodeMCU.

Basicamente ambos estão dentro da mesma rede, e trocam informações dos seus sensores.

Para receber pacotes via UDP do lado do raspberry foi usada a linguagem Python, com sua biblioteca padrão para socket. E para o NodeMCU, usado a biblioteca WiFiUDP.h e ESP8266WiFi.h padrões do NodeMCU ...

O problema aqui é que eu envio e recebo dados normalmente no Raspberry, porém e quando recebo um dado via UDP no NodeMCU, enviado pelo Raspberry, ocorrem alguns caracteres estranhos ..

**Código Python no Raspberry PI**

```
import sys
from ConnetionUDP import ConnetionUDP
from LDR import LDR
from LED import LED
from USC import UniversalCoverter
from OrderScale import OrderScale
import socket


address = "192.168.43.107"

myled = LED()

myldr = LDR()

rbscale = UniversalCoverter(100,10,OrderScale.DESCENDING)

nmcuscale = UniversalCoverter(0,100, OrderScale.ASCENDING)


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,  socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((address, 555))

while True:

    print('Waiting to receive anything ...')
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)

    #data, addr = conn.ReciveData()

    if data.decode() != '':
        print ('Raw data ::: ', data)
        nodeldrvalue = nmcuscale.GetValueUniversalScale(float(data.decode()))
        print ('NodeMCU Value ::: ',  nodeldrvalue, '\n')

    raspberryldrvalue = nmcuscale.GetValueUniversalScale(myldr.GetLDRCount())

    print ('Rasperry Value ::: ',  raspberryldrvalue, '\n')

    if (abs( nodeldrvalue - raspberryldrvalue ) < 4):
        sock.sendto('2'.encode(), addr)
        #conn.SendData(2, addr)
        myled.sendsignalled("blink")

    elif (nodeldrvalue > raspberryldrvalue):
        sock.sendto('0'.encode(), addr)
        #conn.SendData(0, addr)
        myled.sendsignalled("off")

    elif (nodeldrvalue < raspberryldrvalue):
        sock.sendto('1'.encode(), addr)
        #conn.SendData(1, addr)
        myled.sendsignalled("on")
```

**Código C no NodeMCU**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

const char* ssid     = "AP";
const char* password = "10203040";     
int port = 555;
char * ip = "192.168.43.107";

WiFiUDP udp;
char * data;

int sensorPin = A0;

int myvalue = 0;
int readedValue = 0;

int wifiStatus;

void setup() {

    pinMode(D4, OUTPUT);

    // 1 = Disable, 0 = Enable
    digitalWrite(D4, 1);

    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(200);

    // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Your are connecting to; ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    udp.begin(port);
}   

void loop() {

    do_sensor();
    do_connect();
    do_send();
    do_listen();

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("My value: ");
    Serial.println(myvalue);
    Serial.print("Status value: ");
    Serial.println(readedValue);

    if (readedValue == 0) {
      // desliga
      digitalWrite(D4, HIGH);
      delay(2000);
    }
    else if (readedValue == 1) {
      // liga
      digitalWrite(D4, LOW);
      delay(2000);
    }
    else if (readedValue == 2) {
      // pisca
      digitalWrite(D4, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(D4, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(D4, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(D4, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(D4, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(D4, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(D4, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(D4, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(D4, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(D4, HIGH);
    }
}

void do_sensor() {

    myvalue = analogRead(sensorPin); 

}

void do_connect() {

    wifiStatus = WiFi.status();

    if(wifiStatus == WL_CONNECTED) {

        Serial.println("");
        Serial.println("Your ESP is connected!");  
        Serial.println("Your IP address is: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  

        delay(100);
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("");
        Serial.println("WiFi not connected, trying again ...");
        WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
        delay(1000);
    }

    delay(1000);
}

void do_send() {

    if (wifiStatus == WL_CONNECTED) {

        udp.beginPacket(ip, port);
        udp.println(myvalue);
        udp.endPacket();

        Serial.print("Sending: ");
        Serial.println(myvalue);

        delay(5);
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("Connection failed");
        delay(150);
    }

}

void do_listen() {

    if (udp.parsePacket() > 0)
    {
        data = "";

        while (udp.available() > 0)
        {
            char z = udp.read();
            data += z;
        }

        Serial.println("");
        Serial.print("Received data: ");
        Serial.println(data);

        readedValue = atoi(data);
    }
}
```

**Print Screen do que o NodeMCU está recebendo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Raspberry envia apenas 3 valores possíveis: 0, 1 ou 2. Cada um representa uma ação para o NodeMCU, o problema é que o NodeMCU recebe caracteres estranhos como: *vd*, *%s*, *aso* ... (caracteres aparentemente aleatórios)